# Mongo DB Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with entries that look like:

```
{"placeId" : "0b980482-ab4b-4685-95ab-ecc2dcba1837","placeName" : "B8 Göteborg","created" : ISODate("2017-04-09T14:53:01.005Z"),"debitAccount" : "1581","debitAmount" : 26.0,"creditAccount" : "3013","creditAmount" : 23.2142791748047,"taxAccount" : "2620","taxAmount" : 2.78572010993958},
{"placeId" : "0b980482-ab4b-4685-95ab-ecc2dcba1837","placeName" : "B8 Göteborg","created" : ISODate("2017-04-09T14:53:01.005Z"),"debitAccount" : "1581","debitAmount" : 26.0,"creditAccount" : "3014","creditAmount" : 53.2142791748047,"taxAccount" : "2621","taxAmount" : 5.78572010993958}
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
{
    "_id" : "B8 - Göteborg",
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2017-03-24",
            "creditAccounts" : [ 
                {
                    "creditAccount" : "3013",
                    "creditAccountSum" : 23.214279174804
                }, 
                {
                    "creditAccount" : "3014",
                    "creditAccountSum" : 53.2142791748047,
                }, 
            ],
            "debitAccounts" : [ 
                {
                    "debitAccount" : "1581",
                    "debitAccountSum" : 52
                }
            ],
            "taxAccounts" : [ 
                {
                    "taxAccount" : "2620",
                    "taxAccountSum" : 2.78572010993958
                },
                {
                    "taxAccount" : "2621",
                    "taxAccountSum" : 5.78572010993958
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That is per placeName and day have a list of all unique creditAccounts, debitAccounts, taxAccounts and their sum. I have managed to do the grouping for one of the fields and it looks like:

```
db.getCollection('accounting_records').aggregate([
    {$match : {...},  
    {$group: {_id: {placeName :'$placeName',year: {$substr: ['$created',0,4]},month: {$substr: ['$created',5,2]},dayOfMonth: {$substr: ['$created',8,2]},creditAccount:'$creditAccount'}, created: {$max: '$created'},records: { $addToSet: "$$ROOT" }}},
    {$sort : {created : 1}},
    {$group: {_id: {placeName :'$_id.placeName',year: '$_id.year',month: '$_id.month',dayOfMonth: '$_id.dayOfMonth'},created: {$max: '$created'}, creditAccounts:{$push :{creditAccount: '$_id.creditAccount',sum : {$sum: '$records.creditAmount'}, creditAccountName:'$records.creditAccountName'}}}},
    {$sort : {created : 1}},
    {$group : {_id : '$_id.placeName', created: {$max: '$created'}, days : {$push: {date: {$concat: ['$_id.year','-','$_id.month','-','$_id.dayOfMonth']},creditAccounts : '$creditAccounts'}}}},
    {$sort : {_id : 1}},
])
```

But I have no idea how to manage to do the grouping for all 3 creditAccount, taxAccount & debitAccount. Perhaps it's possible with mapReduce but haven't looked in to that since I've read performance is much worse compared to using aggregations framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to `$group` each credit/debit/tax-Account/Amount and calculate sum.



db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id:{_id:"$placeName",date:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d" , date:"$created"}}, creditAccount:"$creditAccount" },
            creditAccountSum : {$sum: "$creditAmount"},
            remaining: {$push: {debitAccount:"$debitAccount",debitAmount:"$debitAmount",taxAccount:"$taxAccount",taxAmount:"$taxAmount"}}
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$remaining"},
    {
        $group: {
            _id:{_id:"$_id._id",date:"$_id.date", debitAccount:"$remaining.debitAccount"},
            debitAccountSum : {$sum: "$remaining.debitAmount"},
            remaining: {$push: {creditAccount:"$_id.creditAccount",creditAccountSum:"$creditAccountSum", taxAccount:"$remaining.taxAccount",taxAmount:"$remaining.taxAmount"}}
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$remaining"},
    {
        $group: {
            _id:{_id:"$_id._id",date:"$_id.date", taxAccount:"$remaining.taxAccount"},
            taxAccountSum : {$sum: "$remaining.taxAmount"},
            remaining: {$push :{creditAccount:"$remaining.creditAccount",creditAccountSum:"$remaining.creditAccountSum", debitAccount:"$_id.debitAccount", debitAccountSum:"$debitAccountSum"}}
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$remaining"},
    {   
        $group : {
                _id:{_id:"$_id._id",date:"$_id.date"},
                creditAccounts:{$addToSet:{creditAccount:"$remaining.creditAccount",creditAccountSum:"$remaining.creditAccountSum"}},
                debitAccounts:{$addToSet:{debitAccount:"$remaining.debitAccount",debitAccountSum:"$remaining.debitAccountSum"}},
                taxAccounts:{$addToSet:{taxAccount:"$_id.taxAccount",taxAccountSum:"$taxAccountSum"}}      
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {_id:"$_id._id"},
            days : {$push: {date:"$_id.date",creditAccounts:"$creditAccounts",debitAccounts:"$debitAccounts", taxAccounts:"$taxAccounts"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:"$_id._id",
            days:"$days"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Test data:

```
{"placeId" : "0b980482-ab4b-4685-95ab-ecc2dcba1837","placeName" : "B8 Göteborg","created" : ISODate("2017-04-09T14:53:01.005Z"),"debitAccount" : "1581","debitAmount" : 26.0,"creditAccount" : "3013","creditAmount" : 23.2142791748047,"taxAccount" : "2620","taxAmount" : 2.78572010993958},
{"placeId" : "0b980482-ab4b-4685-95ab-ecc2dcba1837","placeName" : "B8 Göteborg","created" : ISODate("2017-04-09T14:53:01.005Z"),"debitAccount" : "1581","debitAmount" : 26.0,"creditAccount" : "3014","creditAmount" : 53.2142791748047,"taxAccount" : "2621","taxAmount" : 5.78572010993958},
{"placeId" : "0b980482-ab4b-4685-95ab-ecc2dcba1837","placeName" : "B8 Göteborg","created" : ISODate("2017-05-09T14:53:01.005Z"),"debitAccount" : "1581","debitAmount" : 26.0,"creditAccount" : "3014","creditAmount" : 53.2142791748047,"taxAccount" : "2621","taxAmount" : 5.78572010993958}
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : "B8 Göteborg",
    "days" : [
        {
            "date" : "2017-04-09",
            "creditAccounts" : [
                {
                    "creditAccount" : "3014",
                    "creditAccountSum" : 53.2142791748047
                },
                {
                    "creditAccount" : "3013",
                    "creditAccountSum" : 23.2142791748047
                }
            ],
            "debitAccounts" : [
                {
                    "debitAccount" : "1581",
                    "debitAccountSum" : 52
                }
            ],
            "taxAccounts" : [
                {
                    "taxAccount" : "2621",
                    "taxAccountSum" : 5.78572010993958
                },
                {
                    "taxAccount" : "2620",
                    "taxAccountSum" : 2.78572010993958
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-05-09",
            "creditAccounts" : [
                {
                    "creditAccount" : "3014",
                    "creditAccountSum" : 108.4285583496094
                }
            ],
            "debitAccounts" : [
                {
                    "debitAccount" : "1581",
                    "debitAccountSum" : 52
                }
            ],
            "taxAccounts" : [
                {
                    "taxAccount" : "2621",
                    "taxAccountSum" : 12.57144021987916
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It doesnt really do the trick though since I want each entry in creditAccounts/debitAccounts/taxaccounts to be unique. In the response you posted "debitAccount" : "1581" occurs twice so I guess i must add thoose to the _id top level grouping? 

like: 

_id:{_id:"$placeName",date:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d" , date:"$created"}}, creditAccount : '$creditAccount',debitAccount : '$debitAccount',taxAccount : '$taxAccount'},

Comment: @FrejHåkansson if you want unique items in your list, use $addToSet instead of $push as I have updated in answer.

Comment: Perhaps Im a bit unclear. The field taxAccount/creditAccount/debitAccount are ids and the list: creditAccounts/debitAccounts/taxAccounts should contain the sum of taxAmount/debitAmount/creditAmount for each taxAccount/creditAccount/debitAccount. So in my test data i have 9 possible values of creditAccount so the creditAccounts list for each day should never be greater than 9 instead the sum shuld be increased. Running your suggested answer I get hundreds of entries in each list per day. So number of entries in response is never reduced in your response.

Comment: @FrejHåkansson I hope I understand you now. Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: Your damn right sir. I figured I had to use unwind but could really understand how I would save the result. Thanx alot youre a wizard.

Comment: Hi! Now my data structure has changed somewhat but I whant the same output. Each entry no contains a list of incomeAccounts, debitAccounts and creditAccounts. Each containing name, accountNumber and amount. If I start by unwinding these the sums get screwed up. You think you can help me?